# how to get the selected value from dropdown in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the next value of selected value in the dropdown by JQuery. how to do ?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean by "next value of selected value"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you think of select when you say dropdown: `$("dropdown_selector option:selected").next().val()`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("myselect").options[selectedIndex] < $("myselect").items.length)
      alert($("myselect").options[$("myselect").selectedIndex+1].text);
else
      alert($("myselect").options[$("myselect").selectedIndex].text);
```