# How can I get which radio and which option tags is selected by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have html like that

```
  <input type="radio" name="Gander" value="M" id="Male" />Male
  <input type="radio" name="Gander" value="F" id="Female" /> FeMale


 <select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1">
    <option value="1">PHP</option>
    <option value="2">ASP.NET</option>
    <option value="3">C SHARP</option>
    <option value="4">SQL SERVER</option>
    <option value="5">WCF</option>
</select>
```

i want use jquery to know what is radio button selected and what is option tag selected in dropdownlist1 and stored values in variables

```
//"the value attribute of radio button user selected"

var Gander = ??
```

and

```
 //"the value attr of option that user selected"

var CourseID = ??
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get which radio is selected via jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138859/jquery-how-to-get-selected-radio-button-value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272507/find-out-if-radio-button-is-checked-with-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459659/check-if-any-radio-or-checkbox-is-selected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380230/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803504/how-to-get-the-selected-value-from-dropdown-in-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/to-get-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-select-element-in-jquery

Comment: search: **[jquery] +radio +selected +button**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Gander = $('input:radio[name=Gander]:checked').val();

var CourseID = $('#DropDownList1').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var Gander = $('input[type="radio"]:checked'),
    CourseID = $("#DropDownList1").val();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wgXWg/)

Answer (score 1):

You would use `$('input:radio:checked')` and `$('#myId:selected')`